# Why does this function need to be stored in a variable?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I originally had a problem with this code as I was missing the 'n =' in the last line of code and, as a result, was stuck in an infinite loop.

At this point, while I understand what needed to be corrected I don't understand why. Why can't 'collatz(n)' be enough to call the function and use n as its variable? If anyone could explain this in simple terms (beginner here), I'd really appreciate it.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print (number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print (3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1

print ('Please enter a number.')
n = int(input())
while n != 1:
    n = collatz(n)
```

Comment: The value of `collatz(n)` is the value `collatz` returns. You have to do something with it. `collatz(n)` on its own line is like `2 + 3` on its own line – it makes 5 and… throws it away.

Comment: @Ry: Or similarly, it's the same thing as the difference between `n + 3` and `n = n + 3`.

Comment: Your function returns a result. You want to re-use that result in a next function call, the local variables in a function themselves don't hang around.

Comment: If you entered `42` as the number, then repeatedly calling `collatz(42)` in a loop doesn't make much sense. You want to take the result of `collatz(42)` and pass that result to the *next* call to `collatz(...)`. And you keep repeating that, take the result, pass it to the next call, until the result is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, functions *accept* one or more arguments and *return* a single value or object. Most of the time they don't modify their arguments (and indeed your `collatz` function doesn't attempt to modify its argument).

As an example, this function accepts a variable x, and returns x**2.

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

This function doesn't modify x in place, and the return value won't automatically get assigned to x. Automatic assignment to x would often be unhelpful, and it would be unclear what to do if your function accepted multiple arguments -- which one should get the return result?

You can call this function in various ways, but if you want to do something with the result, you have to store it to a variable or use it immediately:

```
y = 2
z = f(y)

z = f(2)

y = 2
print(f(y))
```

Note that all of these make sense if you think of the function `f` as an object that converts its argument to something else and returns that, but none of them make sense if you expect `f` to modify its argument in place (then `f(2)` would somehow have to convert the number 2 to mean 4 during later references).

For what it's worth, even if you did replace one of the arguments with a new value inside the function, that would not change the value of the corresponding variable outside the function. This is because the variables within the function only point to the corresponding value or object. If you assign a new value to the variable, the local variable within the function will now point to the new value, but the original variable outside the function still points to the old value. On the other hand, you can sometimes modify the underlying value or object rather than creating a new object and pointing the local variable to it. For example, adding an item to a list or dictionary will modify the underlying object, and that change *will* be visible outside your function.

But your collatz function does neither of these - it just calculates a new value and returns it. If you want to do anything with that value, you have to store the result of the function call explicitly. It won't automatically be stored in the argument variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a variable as an argument to a function, a copy of the variable is sent to the function and not the variable itself. 
So in your case n_copy (for example) is sent to your function and not n. 
Now when you modify it within the function it remains in the scope of the function (accessible only by the function) and not the main program.
So when the function ends, nothing happens to n because a copy of n was modified.

Now we come to the return function. Because of the above problem, there is a return function. This will return a value from the function to the main program.
As you modified n within your function, you need to return the modified value to the main program. 
Once you return it to the main program, it has to be stored in a variable, in your case it is n.

As you have started learning Python, you should read about namespace, scopes also. 
Here is the first link from google search
https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html